# Textbox click event in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webforms, textbox, click, event-handling

I am trying to write an onclick event for textbox but VB.net does not seem to support textbox1.click()

I want to open a new form every time someone clicks  on the textbox.
Opening a new form is no problem, but I cant detect the click.
Is there any event for textbox that detects click event?
I saw something like TextboxBase that has Click but I am able to use it well.

please help!

This is how my class looks :
Partial Public Class TextBoxClick
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class

It has some basic load and init events.

I am trying to write a Sub like this :
Private Sub incident_clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Incident.OnClick

Incident.Click does not work either.

I am guessing I need to import some class to access the Click event but I am not sure which.

Thanks is advance

Comment: I used <textarea> tag of html instead of the <asp:textbox> so tht I could get an onclick event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextBox has a Click event, using it is no problem. Your Handles clause however uses *OnClick*, that's not a valid event name. Do make sure this Sub is inside a Form class and not a module.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TextBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click
        MessageBox.Show("Click!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I have tried that but it does not work. I really cannot figure out why coz I did check on msdn library before posting my question here.

Comment: You are stumping everyone here, even though your snippet is *really* wrong.  That doesn't get better until you carefully describe what you do, step by step.  Copying your project to a file sharing service would be another way.

Comment: I am really sorry bout misguiding you and others. But I cannot copy my project (its not really mine and I don't want to get into security issues) But I will try to edit my post to make it more understandable

Comment: Well, one mystery seems solved, this is actually about Web Forms.  Yes, it doesn't have a Click event, you'd have to do something with javascript I imagine.  Tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You could use onFocus event :)

Comment: @JAiro: I am trying to write a sub like this  : Private Sub incident_clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Incident.OnClick

Comment: OnFocus will fire any time the user enters the textbox, either by keyboard, or mouse. That behavior may not be desirable.

Comment: @krum_cho take a look a this post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.click(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @JAiro: I had tried that. But it throws an error saying Event Click not found. And I have mentioned it in the post

Comment: so you should try with another event to realise if the click event is the problem

Comment: @JAiro:thanks for your help & time. Hans Passant recommended that since I am using webforms, it doenst have anything like a click event. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, your code should work as follows:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
                           ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                           Handles TextBox1.Click

    ' Code to handle the event here

End Sub
```

However, you could also try the MouseUp event:

```
Private Sub textbox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, _
                             e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
                             Handles textbox1.MouseUp
    ' Code to handle the event here
End Sub
```

Comment: Mouseup throws an error.I know I am being dense here, but do i need to import anything? I already tried the thing from msdn lib, doenst work

Comment: thanks for your help & time. Hans Passant recommended that since I am using webforms, it doenst have anything like a click event. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
' Will fire if textbox gets focused
Private Sub incident_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles incident.GotFocus
    Debug.Print("inciden got focus")
End Sub

' Will fire if textbox gets mouse clicked
Private Sub incident_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles incident.MouseClick
    Debug.Print("inciden got clicked")
End Sub
```

Comment: @pirho: MouseClick also throws an error, Do i need to import something?

Comment: @pirho: Event MouseClick cannot be found

Comment: Is your project type "Windows Forms Application" ?

Comment: @Pirho: I believe so. I am sure its not a web app. But I did not create this from scratch, I am just working on someone else's project.

Comment: What's your Visual Studio version ?

Comment: @Pirho: thanks for your help & time. Hans Passant recommended that since I am using webforms, it doenst have anything like a click event. Thanks again!

Comment: @Pirho: but the problem is unlike normal html<input> tag, <asp:textbox> doesn't have an onclick event, so I am finding it difficult to use javascript, I guess I should have mentioned that earlier.

Comment: Actually I should have read your question more carefully, there you cleary state that it's web app :)

Comment: "This is how my class looks :
Partial Public Class TextBoxClick Inherits System.Web.UI.Page"

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is having trouble with this, I fixed it by switching to an asp control. My button now looks like this:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

Not sure why, but I now have a working click event.

Answer (score 0):

For me the Textbox_ click event is triggered only when I type a character in that box.

Comment: While this may help OP, it's better to add more details, explanation, examples, etc.  Also you can edit your existing answer.

Answer (score -1):

The textbox click event is triggered only when you type a character in that textbox.
That is disgusting. You may want to try mouse-enter mouse-leave events they are more reliable. Babu V Bassa.

Comment: You can edit your existing answer, in this case, it does not seem to have the need to post another answer.